# Python script automation with systemD - Issues using with nmcli command ( Network Manager)

Tags: systemd, python, networkmanager, services

I am an embedded Electronics Engineer and for 2 two months, I have been developing using a Debian based distribution for one of my clients.

I am actually developing a project that handles  communication and connectivity between the OS and a 4G modem. The modem is managed with AT Commands and the OS connectivity is mainly managed with the `ping` and `curl` commands.

The python script is working fine so far, and has been tested for about 2 weeks now. I am happy with it, and now, I am in the script automation phase.

I have tried to launch my script at boot with both systemd and the old school method (init.d). Both launched the script correctly, but I am having problems with the output of my `ping` and `curl` commands.

Once the modem has been initialized with AT Commands, I am scripting a `nmcli device connect` command from the NetworkManager Package to get an ip from the network, and can then interact with the network using `ping` and `curl`.

When launched as a systemd service or with the help of init.d, the output of the commands are failing. I can not ping the host and the curl result is `000`.

Still, when looking at Network Manager status, there are valid settings including:

1. IP Address
2. DNS Server
3. Default Gateway/Route

But even outside the script, using the `ping` and `curl` commands have the same failures as described earlier.

Looking for solutions, I have found that Network Manager is using a DBUS Session for the service to work and it seems complex to implement that kind of package with script started at boot.

I am bit stuck and I am wondering if anyone has suggestions for troubleshooting further ?

I have already set up Network Manager logging as debug but nothing relevant.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Antoine